# App Sandbox Entitlement Key for opening file by system default player?

Tags: objective-c, xcode, macos, electron, sandbox

I built a video tutorial Mac App, the video files are stored in "/Contents/Resources" folder, the app has a function for playing the video files by system default video player, such as QuickTime. This function works before sandboxing. After sandboxing, this function doesn't work...

So which App Sandbox Entitlement Key can enable opening a file (stored in "/Contents/Resources" folder) by system default app (such as QuickTime player)?

The mac app was built by Electron.

Comment: how do you get the file url for these videos? if using NSBundle.mainBundle you shouldn't need any specific entitlement. Could you post the code? Also did you check Console and saw what kind of sandbox violation was logged?